# How can I embed components contained in a dll into an exe so it can be run from memory?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a program that must be run from memory (through `Assembly.Load(bin)` as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory)) using custom components sitting in a (referenced) .dll.

Since the run-from-memory code runs an .exe, how can the components be embedded in the .exe such that the .dll isn't needed?

I've tried ILMerge, but the resulting .exe wouldn't run from memory.
I've looked at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) but I don't think it works if you've referenced the .dll (which I had to because it contains components on my form)

**Update**

Having read NSGaga's answer, I tried the following:

- Set the components .dll included in the project to be an embedded resource
- Made an addition to `Program.cs`:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace MyApp
  {
      static class Program
      {
          /// <summary>
          /// The main entry point for the application.
          /// </summary>
          [STAThread]
          static void Main()
          {            
              AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=
              (sender, args) =>
              {
                  // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                  String resourceName = "MyApp." +

                      new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

                  using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                  {

                      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

                      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

                      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);

                  }

              };
              Application.EnableVisualStyles();
              Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
              Application.Run(new MainForm());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

*Could not load file or assembly 'MetroFramework, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f91a84759bf584a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

The exception occurs on the `Application.Run(new MainForm());` line. Also, having breakpointed/added message boxes etc, I don't believe the `AssemblyResolve` handler is ever being called - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I think the last method you talk about will work: when the CLR searches a dll it doesn't only look for it at one place, and also the `AssemblyResolve` event will be fired, so you'll find your dll. Doesn't matter that you have referenced the dll in your project. Just try to remove physically the dll from your debug folder and see what happens

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is one of the requirements that you cannot write out the embedded assemblies to a storage device?

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, however I do not mind whether I have one .exe or an .exe with .dlls - it's just the .exe must be load-able and run-able from memory (for my security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered that pretty much - that `manual solution` from Jeffrey Richter should work just fine - ILMerge has issues (e.g. WPF).

it was a long time since I played w/ that but this is rougly what you need to do...

1) Prepare your app a bit - meaning - you cannot load anything until you setup your `AssemblyResolve` handler. That also means anything that is e.g. called from 'main' (even afterwards) will have to be 'resolved' before. In short, move everything you need 'referenced' to some 'later' code,

2) Add the handler - as soon as possible. I'll just repeat that Richter's code w/ some info. Also take a look at the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=
(sender, args) =>
{
    // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    // Lookup what's your namespace in project properties
    String resourceName = "YourAssemblyNamespace." +
        new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
==>
        if (stream == null)
            return null;
==>
        Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
    }
};
```

3) To make a test - move your 'loading' lib code on some 'click' or something - and put a 'Break' (like I did),

4) Add your dll-s  `as embedded resources' - i.e. just like bmp or something, in the root. Add external file - then set it in properties to be 'embedded resources'.

5) Build the app - and notice the change in size, should be pretty much the difference in dll-s,

6) go to your bin dir - and remove dll-s. Don't build the project again and move away from the VS/Debugger,

7) start the app and observe...

**NOTE:** 
You may get exceptions (like the lib you're suggesting) - you need to handle if stream==null. 'Problem' is that all sorts of dll-s are often 'attempted to be loaded (or requested from the app) and they safe fail - since we add the 'handler' we're responsible for softly failing in the same way. See the edited code above.

**Your code edit:**

You may need to move the window starting at a bit later point - have you checked that handler is called (breakpoint and all - do some trace too).

Problem is that the `MainWindow` resolution begins as soon as `it gets visible` - i.e. in the `Main` - and that happens `before` the actual code runs or handler is set up. So...

```
static void Main(){
    ...
    DoAppSetup();
    // Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    // Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
static void DoAppSetup(){
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

...that way your handler should be set up before anything even tries to resolve.

Comment: Interesting, I would very much like to use Richter's solution - I had a go with what you suggested, however with no luck - please see the update on the question.

Comment: I placed an edit - that should do the trick. And you have to work on it a bit - it's impossible for me to debug it for your specific solution. This works, tried and tested before - and I just made a fast check, all works fine on my side. However, your code may require something different. I give you the guidelines, you do the rest :). As for the Richter's code - there is much less there than what I gave you here, this is a worked out example with all the information you need - i.e. the best you can get IMO :)

Comment: +1 Fantastic; thank you very much - that worked a treat. It was creating the `DoAppSetup()` function that made got the handler called at the right time.

Comment: Unfortunately the single .exe still won't run from memory after all that :P

Comment: you gotta persist a bit - see what's actually not working. I tried today - you first compile with Dll referenced, all as normal. You DO NOT remove the 'reference' just delete it physically from the bin dir. Just add 'dll' as any other file - in the root. Make sure your 'namespace' is replaced in the code (YourNamespace). And debug the handler - you'll see if it doesn't load there. It's probably the catch finding the 'resource'. After all that - it looks like - you run the app (no debug, command line) - it goes into handler, loads a resource and continues as normally, works like a charm...

Comment: you can debug that - by putting that 'Debugger...' line - and then it asks you like it has 'an error' - it's no error - just means to enter debugger (I guess you know that, just saying) - you enter and debug session starts as any other, etc. (but you cannot start debugger directly as it'd compile the missing lib).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access the embedded resources directly then just embed them in the EXE, if they're in a third-party DLL then you're not going to be able to lift them out and embed them without running into practicality and potential legal issues.

I'd recommend directly embedding into the EXE if you can.